# How can we change the header text and its color for the Salesforce Einstein chatbot?

Tags: lightning, liveagent, einstein-chatbot

The Einstein Chatbot header has default greeting text as "Hello Guest! An agent is on the way. And this text on header is white in color. I want to change it into a different color, probably darker color. Also, by default it has End Chat button on the header, how to remove that button from there ?

Comment: if your chatbot is used with embedded services, then you can change the header color in that

Comment: I can change the header color, but how about the header text and the text color ? Is there a way to change that ?

Answer (score 1):

Setup -> Embedded Service Deployment Settings -> View (in de button on the right of your embedded service) and 'Edit' in Branding.